# Can I remove directory, then create directory in a single command?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I kinda have a feeling that there is some way to do below in a single command:

`rm -rf folder_name`

`mkdir folder_name`

Is this possible?

Comment: Is `rm .. ; mkdir ..` (that is, using a [command sequence](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184493/consecutive-commands)) not sufficient? These are generally two *distinct* actions - and thus two distinct commands. Alternatively, just delete the *contents* of the directory although will have a different effect on inode, possibly permissions.

Comment: How about just deleting the contents with `rm -rf folder_name/*`?

Answer (score 2):

No, not with the standard utilities (though there's nothing preventing you from *writing* such a beast).

The usual way to do something like this is with a conditional sequence:

```
rm -rf folder_name && mkdir -p folder_name
```

This will do the `rm` and then, provided it returns success, make the directory anew.

One thing you *can* do if you want a simple "command" is to put it in a function:

```
remakedir()
{
    [[ -n "$1" ]] && rm -rf "$1" && mkdir -p "$1"
}
```

Then some simple tests show it in action:

```
pax> remakedir /tmp/xyzzy ; touch /tmp/xyzzy/plugh1 ; ls -al /tmp/xyzzy
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 pax   pax   4096 Jun 23 09:29 .
drwxrwxrwt 10 root  root  4096 Jun 23 09:29 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 pax   pax      0 Jun 23 09:29 plugh1

pax> remakedir /tmp/xyzzy ; touch /tmp/xyzzy/plugh2 ; ls -al /tmp/xyzzy
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 pax   pax   4096 Jun 23 09:29 .
drwxrwxrwt 10 root  root  4096 Jun 23 09:29 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 pax   pax      0 Jun 23 09:29 plugh2
```

Comment: Note that this is removing everything in the current directory, which means that should the current contents be sizeable, new items could be injected while the delete is running, resulting in a much long operation instability period.

Answer (score 1):

Posix does not have a single command that does what you want. But the following will do (mostly) what you want (reduces the window of time when the directory is missing and/or unavailable).

Make a temporary directory (to hold the thing you are about to delete).

```
delete=`mktemp -d ./delete.XXXXXX`
folder="folder_name"
```

Move the existing folder aside (for later deletion). This is the 'critical section',

```
mv ${folder} ${delete}/ && mkdir ${folder}
```

Then delete the (previous) existing at your convenience,

```
if [ -d ${folder} ] ; then rm -rf ${delete}/; fi
```